# Material-UI Snackbar with redux fail on onClose

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

Ok I'm losing my mind. I'm trying to do like a general message component with the [snackbar](https://material-ui.com/demos/snackbars/) component from `Material-UI` and I want it to be controlled by `redux`. The idea is, when I make an asynchronous call to an api the state in redux will set the `show` property to `true` and the message will show up. That is OK and it is rendering fine. The problem is when I click the on the close button, it should dispatch a close function to redux and the state will be set to false. But an error message shows up in console:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string 
>         (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but 
>         got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file 
>         it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `SnackbarContentRaw`.

**generalMessage.jsx**

```
import { hideMessage } from '../../../actions/action_messages';

const _GeneralMessage = (props) => {   return (
    <Snackbar
      ...
      open={props.show}
      onClose={props.closeMessage}
    >
      <SnackbarContentWrapper
        onClose={props.closeMessage}
        ...
      />
    </Snackbar>   ) }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    show: state.mensajes.show,
    tipo: state.mensajes.tipo,
    mensaje: state.mensajes.mensaje
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        closeMessage: () => dispatch( hideMessage() )
    }
}

export const GeneralMessage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(_GeneralMessage);
```

**SnackbarContentWrapper.jsx**

```
const SnackbarContentRaw = (props) => {
  const { classes, className, message, onClose, variant, ...other } = props;
  const Icon = variantIcon[variant];

  return (
    <SnackbarContent
      className={classNames(classes[variant], className)}
      aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
      message={
        <span id="client-snackbar" className={classes.message}>
          <Icon className={classNames(classes.icon, classes.iconVariant)} />
          {message}
        </span>
      }
      action={[
        <IconButton
          key="close"
          aria-label="Close"
          color="inherit"
          className={classes.close}
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>,
      ]}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SnackbarContentRaw);
```

**action_messages.js**

```
import { HIDE_MESSAGE } from './types/messages';

export const hideMessage = () => {
  return { type: HIDE_MESSAGE }
}
```

Am I exporting/importing something wrong or is it the `material-ui` component? Let me know if someone needs another file and I can put them here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a day of digging the internet for answers turns out that it was a problem with the reducer. I was returning different state keys for differents types. My bad.

This is what I had:

```
import { SHOW_MESSAGE, HIDE_MESSAGE } from '../actions/types/messages';

const initialState = {
  show: false,
  tipo: null,
  message: '',
}

export const mensajes = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SHOW_MESSAGE:
      return { show: true, tipo: action.tipo, mensaje: action.mensaje }
    case HIDE_MESSAGE:
      return initialState
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So it was telling me that it was receiving undefined as I was trying to get the key `mensaje` and it only had `message`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove onClose from *SnackbarContentWrapper*, I believe it's enough to provide it in Snackbar. Idk if this helps to solve your problem, but anyway SnackbarContent doesn't need an onClose().

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined
often appear in conditional rendering, when one of children became null or undefined. Check SnackbarContent, maybe there is similar problem inside it.

Comment: I need that prop so the `closeIcon` knows what to do when it is clicked

Comment: I found the problem. I posted and an answer, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the content for the SnackBar in the `action` prop like this:

```
action={[
            <Button key="undo" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={this.handleClose}>
              UNDO
            </Button>,
            <IconButton
              key="close"
              aria-label="Close"
              color="inherit"
              className={classes.close}
              onClick={this.handleClose}
            >
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>,
          ]}
        />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/7jkzwn39qx

Comment: This is how i got it in my `SnackbarContentWrapper` component. I'll update the answer

Comment: I found the problem. I posted and an answer, thank you for your time